# .where('endTime', isGreaterThan: DateTime.now()) not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As part of my query I do:

`.where('endTime', isGreaterThan: DateTime.now())`

And it returns nothing...this makes no sense and it is my intention it works.  If I change `isGreaterThan` to `isNotEqualTo` the record I need is returned.

The model:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class TheModel {
  DateTime endTime;
```

The data in the DB:

```
createdAt: "2022-05-25T20:31:19.068171"
endTime :"2022-05-26T20:31:19.068172".
```

and

```
print("NOW " + DateTime.now().toString());
```

is
`NOW 2022-05-26 00:17:01.411879`

Comment: Are you saying that `var endTime =  DateTime.now()` and `insert endTime` then DB record and endTime is different?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question can you please provide more context?

Comment: Are DateTime.now() and endTime in DB the same moment?

Comment: No, this information is already provided in the question. See the end where I am printing now.